# How to merge pandas dataframe based on substring of column elements python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes A and B. Dataframe A looks like:

```
col1    col2   col3
 a_low   5      6
 a_low   3      10
 a_high  4      4
```

Dataframe B looks like:

```
col1 colB 
 a    90
```

Now, I want to merge df A and B on the substring `a` in col1 from df A and col1 from df B. Hence, the result should be:

```
col1    col2   col3  colB
 a_low   5      6     90
 a_low   3      10    90
 a_high  4      4     90
```

Anyone knows how to do this using `merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `assign()` and `merge()` method:

```
result=dfA.assign(col1=dfA['col1'].str.split('_').str[0]).merge(dfB).assign(col1=dfA['col1'])
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    colB
0   a_low   5       6       90
1   a_low   3       10      90
2   a_high  4       4       90
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the part of string from `col1`, e.g. with `str.split` or `str.extract()`, then either merge or map:

```
dfA['colB'] = (dfA['col1'].str.split('_').str[0]
                  .map(dfB.set_index('col1')['colB']
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` + `insert`:

```
pat = "|".join(df_a.col1)
df_b.insert(0, 'a', df_b['col1'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False))
```